# LWC how to remove a DOM element that is rendered by another lightning component?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

For example I use  in a LWC that I build.
Is it possible to remove an element (for example ) that exists only after  is rendered?

I tried to use query selector inside my .js file:

```
this.template.querySelector('h3');
```

But I can't find the target element this way.

Comment: do you have a simple code of example?